# P7zip preventing CLI prompt

Tags: python, linux, bash, compression, 7zip

I'm using the Pyunpack library in a Python script. It turns out this just uses the p7zip CLI to extract 7zip files. The problem is, if the script runs into a duplicate file, p7zip wants to know whether to overwrite, prompting the user and interrupting the script.

Is there a way I can pre-answer the overwrite prompt from Pyunpack so that my code executes? Or if that's not possible, is there a way to pass the CLI prompts back through Python so the program can at least continue with user input?

If I enter the same command the Python script uses into bash, I get this:

`7z x -o/home/path/to/extract/directory -- /home/path/to/file.7z`

```
file /something/in/the/7z/directory/filename.thing already exists. Overwrite with filename.thing?
(Y)es / (N)o / (A)lways / (S)kip all / A(u)to rename all / (Q)uit?
```

However when I execute it in Python, Python simply hangs in subprocess while waiting for a response to this prompt.

I'd like to use the option auto rename all automatically. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you pass arguments through? So you can use the `-y` flag?

Comment: Sadly Pyunpack doesn't support passing arguments through. Patool doesn't seem to document it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution! Thanks Etan for pointing me in the right direction.

I had to open up patoolib and edit p7zip.py.

Where it defines `extract_7z` I hard-coded the `-y` flag by commenting out:

```
if not interactive:
    cmdlist.append('-y')
```

And adding `cmdlist.append('-y')` right beneath `cmdlist = [cmd, 'x']`.

Now my code is running smoothly!